# Fast way of selecting cubmap face in GLSL

Tags: optimization, opengl, glsl, shader

I'm looking to optimize the following glsl function that does a cubmap face selection. It takes a 3 component vector and returns the face, texcoords for the face and the largest component.

```
vec4 cubemap( vec3 P )
{
    vec4 Coord;
    vec3    s = abs(P.xyz);
    bvec3   b = greaterThan( P.xyz, vec3(0,0,0) );

    if ( all( greaterThanEqual( s.xx, s.yz ) ) )
    {
        if ( b.x )
            Coord = vec4( -P.z, -P.y, 0, s.x );
        else
            Coord = vec4(  P.z, -P.y, 1, s.x );
    } else 
    if ( all( greaterThanEqual( s.yy, s.xz ) ) )
    {
        if ( b.y )
            Coord = vec4(  P.x,  P.z, 2, s.y );
        else
            Coord = vec4(  P.x, -P.z, 3, s.y );
    } else 
    {
        if ( b.z )
            Coord = vec4(  P.x, -P.y, 4, s.z );
        else
            Coord = vec4( -P.x, -P.y, 5, s.z );
    }

    Coord.xy = ((Coord.xy / Coord.w) + 1.0) * 0.5;
    return Coord;
}
```

Comment: Optimize in length or in speed? Also if I remember right wasn't there a builtin function that addresses cubemaps?

Comment: I'll ask the obvious question: why don't you just use a cubemap? The `texture` function will take care of this all for you.

Comment: there are really awesome reasons why I can't use an actual cubemap.  I'm hoping to optimize this function for speed.

Comment: If those reasons are so awsome, why don't you share them with us? Also I think it can not be done much more efficiently, only more elegant.

Answer (score 2):

This way might still be slow, but it doesn't do any branching:

```
vec2 directionToUV(vec3 v) {
    vec3 abs = abs(v);
    float max = max(max(abs.x, abs.y), abs.z); // Get the largest component
    vec3 weights = step(max, abs); // 1.0 for the largest component, 0.0 for the others
    float sign = dot(weights, sign(v)) * 0.5 + 0.5; // 0 or 1

    // Find the uv coordinate 
    float sc = dot(weights, mix(vec3(v.z, v.x, -v.x), vec3(-v.z, v.x, v.x), sign));
    float tc = dot(weights, mix(vec3(-v.y, -v.z, -v.y), vec3(-v.y, v.z, -v.y), sign));
    vec2 uv = (vec2(sc, tc) / max) * 0.5 + 0.5;

    // Offset into the right region of the texture
    float offsetX = dot(weights, vec3(0.0, 1.0, 2.0));
    float offsetY = sign;
    uv.x = (uv.x + offsetX) / 3.0;
    uv.y = (uv.y + offsetY) / 2.0;
    return uv;
}
```

Where the cube maps is arranged like

```
        +----+----+----+
        |  x |  y |  z |
        +----+----+----+
        | -x | -y | -z |
        +----+----+----+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can optimize out dynamic branches.  I'm not sure if that will improve performance, but in this case you can certainly try it.  It sometimes improves shader code performance.

For example for the first conditional, you could /try/ something like:

```
int condition=(s.x>=s.y)*(s.x>=s.z)*(b.x);
Coord = condition*vec4( (1.-2.*condition)*P.z, -P.y, condition, s.x );
```

And so on...I imagine this will give you performance gains of some kind, if only marginal, because to my knowledge dynamic branches on the GPU are expensive when highly divergent and should generally only be used to conditionally eliminate larger blocks of operations.

That's the most obvious thing I see.